# How to select multi words in window.getSelection

Tags: javascript, getselection

How to select multi words in `window.getSelection`.

In this code, if I choose `tweenen paragrap`, it will locked word `paragraphs` and missed `between. And I need select both 2 words.

Or even I choose 3 words `dd 2 spa`, it will select 3 words `add 2 spaces`. thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Selected() {
        var sel;
        if ((window.getSelection) && (sel = window.getSelection()).modify) {
            sel = window.getSelection();
            if (!sel.isCollapsed) {
                sel.modify("move", "backward", "word");
                sel.modify("extend", "forward", "word");
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<p>put returns between paragraphs, for linebreak add 2 spaces at end</p>
<input type="button" onclick="Selected();" value="selected">
```

Comment: **Please** use Rangy when working with ranges and selections. http://code.google.com/p/rangy/

Comment: @Matt Ball, Rangy can not select full words, If I select `dd 2 spa`, it just show `dd 2 spa` and not `add 2 spaces`.

Comment: @cj333: You're right. It's something I intend to add to Rangy in the relatively near future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the button to snap the selection to whole words. If so, here's how you can do it:

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uCHVQ/1/

Code:

```
function Selected() {
    var sel;
    if ((window.getSelection) && (sel = window.getSelection()).modify) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (!sel.isCollapsed) {

            // Detect if selection is backwards
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.setStart(sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset);
            range.setEnd(sel.focusNode, sel.focusOffset);
            var backwards = range.collapsed;
            range.detach();

            // modify() works on the focus of the selection
            var endNode = sel.focusNode, endOffset = sel.focusOffset;
            sel.collapse(sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset);
            if (backwards) {
                sel.modify("move", "forward", "word");
                sel.extend(endNode, endOffset);
                sel.modify("extend", "backward", "word");

            } else {
                sel.modify("move", "backward", "word");
                sel.extend(endNode, endOffset);
                sel.modify("extend", "forward", "word");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(By the way, is that code originally from something I've posted? It looks familiar but I can't find it).